# How to get the products based on above 3 star rating in magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I would like to show the prdoucts based on the above 3 star rating using custom collection method.

```
public function getProductCollection()
    {

        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();        
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->joinField('rating_score',
        'review_entity_summary',
        'rating_summary',
        'entity_pk_value=entity_id',
        array('entity_type'=>1, 'store_id'=> $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId(), 'rating_summary'=> 100),
        'right'
        );
         $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => 1) );

        $collection->setPageSize(10); // fetching only 3 products        
        return $collection;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Replace rating summary value 100 to 60**

public function getProductCollection()
    {

```
    $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();        
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->joinField('rating_score',
    'review_entity_summary',
    'rating_summary',
    'entity_pk_value=entity_id',
    array('entity_type'=>1, 'store_id'=> $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId(), 'rating_summary'=> 60),
    'right'
    );
     $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => 1) );

    $collection->setPageSize(10); // fetching only 3 products        
    return $collection;
}
```